# Як відрізняти росіянізми від збігів/слів зі спільним коренем?

Tags: росіянізм

Цікавить, чи є в когось якась загальна методика, словник тощо для визначення, чи є слово росіянізмом?

Бо нерідко українські слова вважають росіянізмами лише через те, що в російській мові теж є такі слова (загальновідомі приклади "лице", "держати").

Ґуґлом знаходжу лише окремі слова чи вкрай маленьки списки ([тут наприклад](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC)).

Наприклад, якщо слово "просьба" звинувачують у тому, що воно росіянізм, як мені переконатися, що воно дійсно росіянізм, чи довести, що це цілком нормальне українське слово?

Comment: Хотілось би ще дізнатись про визначення терміну "росіянізм". Утворення слова від дієслова (`бороти`, `просити`) за допомогою приєднання закінчення `-ба` є природнім (`боротьба`, `просьба`). Сам корінь теж український.

Comment: @SassaNF дякую за додатковий аргумент на захист "просьби" :)
На вікі є велика стаття про те, що це таке (https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Росіянізм).
Стисло: запозичення з російської, найчастіше мається на увазі зайве апозичення до української, коли вже існує інше, питомо українське слово з таким значенням.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Треба дивитися в авторитетних словниках. Чудову добірку чудових старих добрих авторитетних словників зібрано [ось тут](http://r2u.org.ua/). Обираєте там зверху посередині у списку, що спадає, «Серед головних російських слів», зліва зверху в поле вводите російське слово, на яке скидається українське слово, яке ви хочете перевірити, та тиснете «Знайти». А далі по довоєнних словниках дивіться, чи було воно вже тоді. Як не було, то це ґарантія, що воно – росіянізм.

Ще [можна подивитися](http://sum.in.ua/) в високоавторитетному 11-томному Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови, але його видавали в 70-х — 80-х роках, тому там треба обережно, там цитати з творів класиків української літератури, тож треба знати, хто міг росіянізми сипати, а хто ні. Та з часом приходить досвід виявлення отого, про що ви питали.

Comment: Приймаю, адже це безперечно корисна відповідь, і нічого ліпшого наразі немає... Але я сподіваюся, що колись тут зʼявиться краща відповідь )

Answer (score 5):

Вас цікавить нормативність в українській мові слова, схожого на російське, чи сам факт запозичення з російської? Це не одне й те ж. Слово може бути питомим, але впасти в немилість через схожість і потрапити до застарілих, невживаних у сучасному контексті (як сталося з го́родом, наприклад, яке нині здебільшого сприймається як русизм, не будучи ним). Або ж слово може бути русизмом, але при цьому засвоїтися мовою, потрапити до словників, можливо, набути нових значень, відмінних від російської (взяти, для прикладу, «покажчик» — цілком літературне українське слово, що обросло в українській мові великою кількістю значень (а в російській практично забулося) — проте, нетипова для української мови побудова з допомогою -чик (як у «застройщик», «извозчик» — українська в подібних випадках надає перевагу -ник: візник, забудовник) може вказувати на давнє запозичення його з російської). Ну а далі, якщо русизм є в авторитетних словниках (та інших джерелах), його слід вважати нормативним. Після цього можна лише суб'єктивно вирішити, подобається нам цей конкретний словниковий русизм (і словник загалом) чи не подобається, але це вже не методика, а питання смаку — комусь, як мені, ріже очі невластива форма чи звучання, хтось орієнтується на мову рідного села й улюблених книжок, хтось нічого не тямить сам і лише прислухається до чиєїсь авторитетної думки.

Comment: +1 за -*чик*. Щодо того, що якщо вписано в словники, то вже нічого не поробиш, не згоден.

Comment: В академічні словники просто-так слова зі стелі не вписують — як правило, мають бути джерела, на які ці словники спираються. Тобто, позбуваючись словникового русизму, вам доведеться також довести недостовірність чи невідповідність тих джерел. Крім того, присутність активно вживаного слова у словнику сприяє його використанню — відтак, кількість джерел зростає, слово вкорінюється й узвичаюється.

Comment: Цікавить нормативність в українській мові слова, схожого на російське, яке звинувачують у тому, що воно "росіянізм". Незважаючи на визначення в СУМі, я зазвичай зустрічав слово "росіянізм" саме з забарвленням "невластива українській мові калька з російської".

Comment: До речі, «калька» й «запозичення» — не одне й те ж. Напр., рос. «кислород» — калька з «oxygen», послівним перекладом якого він є. І хоча спорідненість мов часто створює плутанину між запозиченням з російської та калькою з російської, використовувати слово «калька» як ярлик для будь-якого небажаного русизму — помилка. «Калька» стосується лише копіювання моделі іншомовного слова чи звороту, «запозичення» — прямого копіювання слова. Напр., комсомол — пряме запозичення, а колгосп — калька (при цьому, обидва нормативні).