# Питомі та усталені слова. Потребую допомоги з методом визначення

Tags: означення, нормативність

Розмовляючи про слова ми часто вживаємо словосполучення *усталене в українській мові слово* та *питоме слово української мови*. Такі словосполученні як правило підкріплюють аргументацію щодо доречності чи недоречності використання певного слова у мовленні.

[**Усталене**](http://sum.in.ua/s/ustalenyj) в цих випадках означає

> Сталий, стійкий, який закріпився у певній формі.

[**Питомий**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pytomyj):

> Характерний для кого-, чого-небудь; притаманний комусь, чомусь.

Для визначення *усталеності* певного слова можна звернутися до [словників або сучасних текстів](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9/92). І якщо таке слово та його словоформи зустрічаються у більше ніж одному авторитетному джерелі, то слово можна вважати усталеним.

Мої питання полягають ось у чому:

1. **Чи не є *питоме слово* простим синонімом *усталеного слова*?**
2. якщо ні і між ними є різниця, то:
   *Чи існує метод чи хоча б набір евристик застосовуючи які довільна **персона**, доклавши за розумний час поміркованого обсягу зусиль, зможе з достатніми шансами визначити чи є власне **питомим**?*

Comment: пов'язане питання http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/63/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D1%96-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: так, але з одного боку, наприклад, `шпацер` чи то `батяр` цілком можливо зустріти у літературних текстах, тобто, згідно з моїм баченням, вони є усталеними, принаймні, діалектизмами, вони не є росіянізмами, але вони очевидно запозичені. З іншого боку ми маємо ще більш давніше запозичені з Візантії [грецизми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) які може й іноді звучать архаїчно, але я не можу ніяк сумніватися у тому що вони є питомими

Comment: пов'язане ≠ дубль. Мені просто здалося, що з **того** боку буде цікаво прочитати й це

Comment: також пов'язані http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/303/92 та http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/359/92. варто подумати над окремим тегом

Comment: "притаманний/а/е" та "усталений/а/е" аж ніяк не є синонімами. <br>
І як щодо усталених помилок? ))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ви провели чудову підготовчу роботу і з'ясували формальне значення двох термінів.
І тому, щоб відповісти на запитання, достатньо лише одного (але важливого) зауваження.

## Коротка відповідь

- *«питоме»* слово — це таке слово, яке ми розглядаємо як воно є, і яке **міняється** разом із еволюцією мови;
- *«усталене»* слово — це таке слово, яке написано у словниках, і **не міняється**.

---

## Довга відповідь

У лінгвістиці є два принципово відмінні підходи: дескриптивний і прескриптивний.

**Дескриптивна лінгвістика** вивчає мову такою, *якою вона є*.
Лінгвісти бачать дійсний, актуальний вжиток слів, морфології, лексики тощо і *виводять правила*, які могли б описати це явище. Якщо правило невірне або застаріло, змінюють правило.
Цей підхід широко вживаний у країнах Європи і Заходу.

Наприклад, дуже легко прослідкувати перетворення слова *electronic mail* (1980-і) спочатку у *e-mail* (1990-і), і тепер це слово отримало форму *email*, і від нього навіть почали утворюватися похідні форми, як-то *emailing*. Більше того, наразі помітні ознаки перетворення цього терміну у *mail*, і якщо тенденція залишиться, слово *email* буде повністю замінено на *mail*.

**Прескриптивна лінгвістика**, навпаки, вивчає мову такою, *якою вона має бути*, з точки зору того чи іншого канонічного джерела.
Спеціально призначені люди *спочатку пишуть правила*, а потім примушують інших користуватися цими правилами.
Такий підхід вживається на Сході, особливо на територіях, **де мова має ознаки штучного створення**.

Наприклад, до граматичної реформи Мао Цзедуна 1952 р. у КНР існувало [багато діалектів](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varieties_of_Chinese), які були далекі до взаємної зрозумілості ([mutual intelligibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility)) один з одним. Створення єдиної мови вимагало силового підходу. Фактично, відбувалося нав'язування населенню мовних правил, які директивно були оголошені **усталеними**.
Дуже подібна ситуація виникла у 18-19-му століттях у Московському царстві, а потім і у Російській імперії, коли влада примушувала поневолені народи, які користувалися мовами різних мовних груп, до канцеляриту, яким не просто «не користувалися в народі», а якого до [реформи Карамзіна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.96.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.8C.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.97_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B8) взагалі не існувало.

---

## Висновок

Враховуючи вищенаведене, дуже легко вивести евристичне правило, яке сформульовано на початку цієї відповіді:

- якщо словом, терміном, чи правилом користуються в дійсності, і якщо ми **змінюємо розуміння** щодо того, «як буде правильно», разом із еволюцією мови — це *питоме*;
- якщо слово написано у словнику, і головним аргументом є його «канонічність», «правильність», **«діди так писали, і ми так писатимемо»** — це *усталене*.

**Мнемонічне правило**. Зауважте, що слово «питомий» у математиці/фізиці має значення «відносний»: *питома вага*. Воно може мінятися разом із контекстом.

---

## Почитати

- [Amy Reynolds: Understanding Prescriptive vs. Descriptive Grammar](http://amyrey.web.unc.edu/classes/ling-101-online/tutorials/understanding-prescriptive-vs-descriptive-grammar/)
- [How do various frameworks account for situations when multiple cases can be assigned?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/9566/1009)