# Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"?

Tags: from-russian, відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Перекладаю з російської таке речення :

> При повороте элемента...

переклав як

> При повороті елемента...

але засумнівався, так як також зустрічав форму родового відмінку з закінченням на **у**.

[Slovnyk.ua](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%E5%EB%E5%EC%E5%ED%F2&x=0&y=0) наводить обидва варіанти, тому буду вдячний за роз'яснення.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Процитую допис "[Родовий відмінок однини іменників чоловічого роду другої відміни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.96.D0.BD.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_-.D0.B0.2C_-.D1.8F)"  з вікіпедії.

**Закінчення `-а`, `-я`**

- Назви осіб, власні імена та прізвища, а також персоніфіковані
  предмети та явища ( учителя, Андрія)
- Назви тварин і дерев (вовка, дуба)
- Назви предметів та архітектурних деталей (олівця, карниза)
- Назви населених пунктів та планет (Харкова, Юпітера)
- Інші географічні назви з наголосом у родовому відмінку на кінцевому
  складі, а також із суфіксами присвійності `-ов`, `-ів` (`-єв`), `-ин` (`-їн`)  (Дністра, Любичіва)
- Назви мір довжини, ваги, часу тощо; назви грошових знаків; числові
  назви (місяця, процента, тижня, карбованця, мільйона )
- Назви місяців і днів тижня (вівторка, жовтня)
- Назви машин та їх деталей (комбайна, мотора)
- Терміни іншомовного походження, які означають **елементи будови чогось**, конкретні предмети, геометричні фігури та їх частини, а також українські за походженням суфіксальні слова-терміни  (атома, ромба, іменника)

**Закінчення `-у`, `-ю`**

- Речовини, маси, матеріали  (азоту, гіпсу, льоду)
- Збірні поняття, а також назви сортів плодових дерев. Сюди належать назви кущових і трав'янистих рослин (атласу, пролетаріату, бузку)
- Назви будівель, споруд (ґанку, магазину)
- Назви установ, закладів, організацій (інституту, штабу)
- Переважна більшість слів зі значенням місця, простору тощо, а також
  їх зменшені форми на `-к` (лугу, майдану, світу)
- Явища природи (вогню, вітру)
- Назви почуттів ( гніву, жалю)
- Назви процесів, станів, властивостей, ознак, формацій, явищ
  суспільного життя, **загальних і абстрактних понять** (бігу, світогляду, шуму)
- Терміни іншомовного походження, що означають фізичні або хімічні процеси, частину площі й т. ін., а також літературознавчі терміни (синтезу, сюжету)
  Назви ігор, танців та абстрактних творів мистецтва (музичних, кінематографічних)  ( вальсу, волейболу)
- Більшість складних безсуфіксних слів (крім назв істот) (манускрипту, водогону)
- Переважна більшість префіксальних іменників із різними значеннями
  (крім назв істот) (вислову, побуту)
- Назви річок, озер, гір, островів, півостровів, країн, областей,
  штатів і т. ін.  (Амуру, Алжиру)

Там же знаходимо прямою мовою

> **елемента** (конкретне) — **елементу** (абстрактне)

Контекст

- Ядро атома складається з протонів (число яких відповідає атомному
  числу хімічного **елемента**)
- Зв'язок моральних норм з реальною практикою людського життя випливає також і з тієї обставини, що нормою називається, крім відповідного **елементу** свідомості, ще й просто певний середній випадок або показник, певна усталена риса того чи іншого об'єктивного масового явища або процесу.

Comment: У відповіді  жирним позначено те, що стосується мого прикладу.  Правила узяті з вікіпедії, а вона, в свою чергу, посилається на  [§ 48. Родовий відмінок // Український правопис. — К.: Наук. думка, 2012. — С. 83-86.](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par48). Додатково, "Ма́сова ча́стка елеме́нту" - назва [статті](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Масова_частка_елементу) з вікіпедії

Comment: Ма́сова ча́стка елеме́нту - абстракція. Визначення наведене у прикладі. Не існує масових часток елементу у природі. Це якась математична величина яку ми можемо розрахувати. Азот, кисень, водень - конкретні (не абстракція) хімічні елементи таблиці Менделєєва. Кожен з них має властивість атомне число елемента.

Comment: Поміняв приклад на менш суперечливий.

Answer (score 3):

Конкретна річ - -а, абстрактна - -у. Я гадаю, у вас тут значення конкретне, тому «елемента».

Comment: Дякую, могли б ви ще навести джерело інформації на яке посилаєтесь?

Answer (score 2):

Наявна [відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2854/8) цілком вичерпно роз'яснює формальні правила, за якими відбувається вибір закінчення `-а` або `-у` у родовому відмінку. Ці правила присутні у багатьох підручниках української мови і вважаються канонічними.

Менше з тим, на цьому сайті постійно виникають [запитання-дублікати](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/7003/8), автори яких не можуть добрати правильну категорію до іменника. Отже, цей допис відповідає на додаткове запитання:

> Чи є [емпіричне правило](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE) (*rule of thumb*), яке дозволяє інтуїтивно визначити категорію слова щодо закінчення родового відмінку однини іменників чоловічого роду?

---

#### Відповідь: так, таке правило є:

Іменники, що позначають **одухотворені** (*animate*) істоти (у тому числі, сакралізовані або іншим чином штучно одухотворені предмети) отримують закінчення `-а`.
Іменники, що позначають **неодухотворені** (*inanimate*) предмети, отримують закінчення `-у`.

#### Багато слів

Україномовних досліджень на цю тему нема. Найближче джерело — проф. Залізняк, але він, унаслідок своєї політичної позиції, не писав українською, незважаючи на українське прізвище. :) Тому (*у дужках*) я вказуватиму ключові англомовні слова, за якими можна ґуґлити подальшу інформацію.

- В українській, як і в багатьох слов'янських мовах, іменники мають граматичний рід (*grammatical gender, GG*) і число (*grammatical number*).
- Ці обидві категорії впливають на відмінювання іменника.
- Іменники *чоловічого роду* мають *додаткову* характеристику, яка називається **одухотвореність** (*animacy*) та особистість (*personhood*).
  Історично це виглядало у вигляді ієрархії:

  - *personhood* — іменники на позначення людей (неполіткоректно, лише чоловічого роду)
  - *animate* — іменники на позначення одухотворених істот (тварин, а також найбільш цінних предметів побуту, в основному, інструментів) — граматично включає в себе попередню категорію;
  - інші іменники чоловічого роду — неодухотворені;
  - іменники жіночого роду;
  - іменники середнього роду;
- Іменники на позначення особистих та одухотворених істот (звісно, вони були лише чоловічого роду) відмінювалися на `-а` (*a-stem noun paragidm*)
- Інші іменники відмінювалися на `-у` (*u-stem noun paragidm*)
- Це стосується не лише родового відмінку, але і знахідного. Більше того, є таке явище як *genitive-accusative syncretism* (GA syncretism), змішування форм закінчень родового та знахідного відмінків. І це явище також притаманне animate іменникам.

Як вказано у коментарях, спорідненим явищем є [Іменники-назви істот і неістот](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82), щоправда, з тією різницею іменники-назви істот, за означенням, відповідають на запитання *хто?* у той час, як більшість іменників на позначення одухотворених відповідають на запитання *що?*

---

#### Висновки

Основне питання, на яке треба відповісти, щоб визначити категорію іменника, це **наскільки «живим» ви вбачаєте істоту або предмет, позначений іменником**. Якщо «живий», то закінчення `-а`, інакше — `-у`.

- Якщо йдеться про людину або тварину, то все очевидно.
- Історично, релігійним предметам, а також основним господарчим інструментам, від яких залежало фізичне виживання, надавалося додаткової сакральності, а значить, і одухотвореності.
- Українська мова демонструє також таке явище, як [facultative-animacy](/questions/tagged/facultative-animacy), де неживі предмети деяких категорій (наприклад, інформаційного характеру, бо вони ніби могли «говорити», як-то [*лист*](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6271/8)), також отримували одухотвореність.
- Попередній пункт цілком можна розширювати. Наприклад, під явище факультативної одухотвореності можна підкласти **предмети інформаційних технологій**: *сервер, процес, потік, [фронтенд, бекенд](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/7003/8), баґ, контейнер, репорт* жартома наділяються особистісними характеристиками як-то гонором, характером, слухняністю чи бешкетництвом, і тому вони також можуть отримувати закінчення `-а`
- Натомість, предмети  об'єкти, над якими виконуються якісь дії (*«при повороті елементу»* із тексту запитання) можна вважати такими, що не мають власної «особистості» і тому я б не вважав великою помилкою, якби вони відмінювалися на `-у`.

---

#### Чтиво

- Sebastian Kempgen et. al. — Die slavischen Sprachen / The Slavic Languages. Halbband 1 (2009), ISBN: 978-3110156607. Паперова книга [є на Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013E9C114) за страшні гроші, але мені вдалося завантажити PDF [звідси](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329139819_Die_slavischen_Sprachen_The_Slavic_Languages_Ein_internationales_Handbuch_zu_ihrer_Struktur_ihrer_Geschichte_und_ihrer_Erforschung_An_International_Handbook_of_their_Structure_their_History_and_their_), сторінки 152-160 містять статтю Emily Klenin — "Animacy, Personhood"
  *(власна оцінка: стаття читається як детектив, не відірватися)*
- [facultative-animacy](/questions/tagged/facultative-animacy) — це явище також близько споріднене з обговорюваним питанням

Comment: Це дещо смішно, бо тут неправильна відповідь. Спробую надати свою.

Comment: Щиро захоплений глибиною дослідження.

Comment: Щодо фінального висновку — я правильно розумію, що, на Вашу думку, багато слів (зокрема _бекенд_, _фронтенд_) дозволяють обидва закінчення, і _фактично вибір залежить від суб'єктивного відчуття мовця/письменника_?

Comment: @Sasha, саме так вважаю. Сам мовець обирає, наскільки одухотвореним він вважає предмет. А дослідники дотримуються [дескриптивного підходу](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/437/8), мовцеві у цьому не заважають, а натомість, спостерігають і формалізують у підручниках. Ну і знов-таки, будь-яке емпіричне правило є суб'єктивним і має винятки. А відсутність україномовних досліджень може викликати заперечення дослідників, які звикли до класичного підходу.

Comment: Якщо я не помиляюся, проф. Залізняк помер у 2017 році, тому "...не писав українською".

Answer (score 1):

*Це по сутї розлога заувага до [відповідї](/a/7011/585), де розказано про *animacy*…*

---

Що чомусь:

- Перекладено як *одухотворенісь*, хоча вже давно є усталені [*істота* і *неістота*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82) (*inanimacy*).
- Привʼязано до парабіжності закінченнь **-у** та **-а**, хоча то насправдї до парабіжности відмінків знахідного і родового. Тут це було би *[знайшов] елемента* проти *елемент*.

Згадана ланка про [*лист*](/q/6271/8) теж нічого не каже про істоту. Це просто зразкова проблема [***синкретизму***](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) — злиття — знахідного і родового¹, що не дивно, бо різні правила для істот і неістот, загального і окремого ітд. Це стосується будь-якого роду, тут наприклад при дїйойменниках: *Іди **сіна** косити. Пішов **риби** ловити. Прийдеш до мене **барвіночку** рвати. Вийшла мати **води** брати. Покинь **відер** набивати. Іде мати **невістки** будити. Ніде **правди** (**гріха**) діти* й т. інше. Або навпаки в [знахідний](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine19-16.pdf), особливо коли дїйослово з *не* чи коли треба вказати *визначеність*, правда, сам Бєляєв вказує на вплив російської мови. Тож мішанина родів і є причиною богатьох запитаннь. Чисто умовно, проблема вирїшиться новими нормами або повним зливом родів.

Але навіть ві випадку неістот — *[пишу] лист* чи *листа* — тут розглядають не перетвір до істоти, а якраз до розряду родового з **-у** та **-а**, що відповідає за [***конкретність*** і **абстракність**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D1%96_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96)²: *[написав] лист* (загально) проти *листа* (окремого). Теж начебто стосується чоловічого. Дуже сумнїваюся, що тут всі *конкретні неістоти* стають *істотами*: *[немає] зошита, годинника* і, власне, *листа* ітд; але при цьому *елемента* (конкретне) і *елементу* (абстрактне), *вогню* (інше абстракне для прикладу).

Знов ж чергове *але*, аби було веселїше: маємо щось дуже подібного до попереднього: [***частинний родовий відмінок***](//r2u.org.ua/node/199), що латинською ще відомий як ***партитивний***. Стосується не лише чоловічого: *[випив] воду* (повністю) проти *води* (частину). Сулима наводить *[дай] хліба* як коротку форму до *шматок хліба*. Також ним зазначено, що після числових назов, починаючи від *пʼять*, завжди буває родовий частинний. З певними дїйословами може значити частинність самих їх, особливо якщо предмет неподїльний: *[дати] віз* (назавжди) проти *воза* (тимчасово).

---

1. Що відносно поширене явище: [фінська і естонська](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncretism_(linguistics)#Other_languages), [ґрецька](//www.academia.edu/4244548/ACCUSATIVE_GENITIVE_SYNCRETISM_IN_THE_NOMINAL_INFLECTION_OF_MODERN_GREEK_DIALECTS_DIONYSIOS_MERTYRIS). Приклади наведені Сулимою — див. ланку, де згадано *частинний родовий відміннок*.
2. Чимось віддалено нагадує анґлійське *the*.

Comment: Цікаво, дякую. Термінологію спробую виправити. *Риби ловити* — класичний випадок Partitive case, а *ніде правди діти* — Abessive case, обидва які злилися з Genitive. Це усе ref. Залізняк, 1967.

Comment: По-моєму, інший термін замість істота і неістота використано доволі вдало: (1) щоб у читачів не виникало бажання звести це до чітко зафіксованого зі шкільних уроків «кіт — істота, дерево — (граматично) неістота»; (2) від «істота і неістота» важко утворити прикметник на зразок одухотворений і іменник на зразок одухотвореність.

Comment: Як не дивно, дихотомія «написав листа / написав лист» і дихотомія «нема елемента / нема елементу», здається, пов'язані. Я вже давно помічав, що випадки на зразок «написав листа» тяжіють до використання -а навіть у тих словах, які в словниках з -у (наприклад, «отримав приза»). Цілком можливо, що Be Brave Be Like Ukraine має ряцію — і ОБИДВА явища історично прив'язані до дихотомії «істота / неістота». (Або згадати про «Чи в доща є батько?» з перекладу «Біблії» Куліша — взагалі-то дощ має бути з -у, але, можливо, саме конотація істоти змусила перекладача тут написати -а.)

Comment: Загалом, мені здається, щоб сперечатися з його відповіддю, треба прочитати відповідний фрагмент Sebastian Kempgen Die slavischen Sprachen, але наразі гадки не маю, як його швидко знайти.

Comment: @Sasha, Re як знайти: я в дописі прописав посилання, звідки мені вдалося скачати PDF. Не знаю щодо легальності, лише сподіваюся, що наше дослідження має академічну мотивацію.