# Запитання щодо закінчень родового відмінка математичних термінів

Tags: родовий-відмінок

У словах *logarithm, gradient, argument, algorithm, element* (українською) яке порекомендуєте вживати закінчення родового відмінка? Словники від УМІФ (і, здається, правопис) кажуть **-а** (принаймні коли це мат. терміни). Словники Мейнаровича кажуть **-у**. (Але я не певен, що словники Мейнаровича послідовні — у багатьох математичних термінах вони все-таки дають **-а**, наприклад *оператора*.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: елемента (конкретне) — елементу (абстрактне) https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Родовий_відмінок_однини_іменників_чоловічого_роду_другої_відміни

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Щодо родового відмінка, то користуйтеся ліпше довідником «дзвона чи
дзвону?» http://rodovyi-vidminok.wikidot.com/a. В УМІФ забагато помилок.

Щодо **-у** в Мейнаровича, то загалом є тендеція (мовна) до розширення
вжитку **-у**, тож, може, цим викликано **-у** там, де його не мало б бути.
Пишіть *логаритма, градієнта*. Щодо *аргумента/у*, то я б
залишив подвійне закінчення. якщо аргумент стосується математики —
**-а**, якщо аргумент — доказ/підстава — то **-у** [хоча словники варіант **-а** не дають, я б розглядав це як помилку].

Щодо *елемента/у*, то 2 закінчення, залежно від значення.

*Алгоритм*, хоч і стосується математики, але це по суті
послідовність/сукупність/набір дій, тож *алгоритму*, як *набору*. Тобто
як *плану, розв'язку, догмату*.

Comment: Чому довідник > УМІФ і чому це помилки?