# Родовий відмінок для слів на кшталт бекенд, фронтенд

Tags: запозичені-слова, відмінювання, іншомовні-слова, родовий-відмінок

Я помітив, що обидва варіанти використовуються дуже часто — з закінченням на -а та з закінченням на -у. Це можна легко перевірити в Google.

Отже, як правильно?

- Розробка бекенда/фронтенда
- Складові бекенда/фронтенда
- Завдання стосується бекенда/фронтенда

Чи

- Розробка бекенду/фронтенду
- Складові бекенду/фронтенду
- Завдання стосується бекенду/фронтенду

As explained by Sasha in the comments, this is not exactly the same as element. Seems like there are certain reasons why it can have either of the possible endings. So theoretically a person who understands these rules better than me or Sasha could suggest why these words must have certain ending. Or, actually if both variants are possible, as in the case with element, also explain it.

Maybe it could be бекенда/фронтенда when referring to a certain backend/frontend, and бекенду/фронтенду, when referring to backend/frontend in general?

For example:

- Правки бекенда вже на проді
- Книжка розповідає про нюанси розробки бекенду, який має підтримувати високі рівні навантаження

Or should it be only one ending in every case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: No, element is a quite different word. But thanks for the suggesion!

Comment: Actually, it is the same — unless you provide with an evidence explaining why it is not. Please [edit] your post to tell us why.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine має рацію. Відповідь на [Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83) є відповіддю на ваше питання, оскільки в обох випадках застосовуються правила правила відмінювання іменників чоловічого роду другої відміни за родовим відмінком. Тому ваше питання - дублікат.

Comment: Крім того, відповідь на ваше знаходитися в гуглі за 5 секунд максимум, адже правила відмінювання іменників чоловічого роду другої відміни за родовим відмінком є *буквально* на будь-якому ресурсі із матеріалами по українській мові. Тому також є кейс для того, щоб стверджувати, що таке питання демонструє недостатній рівень дослідження теми.

Comment: Голосую, щоб закрити.

Comment: А я, якщо чесно, на боці автора. Правила вибору -а/-у доволі туманні, мені кожного разу доводиться перечитувати їх від початку до кінця, і навіть після цього часто відповідь неочевидна (зокрема конкретний випадок може підпадати під різні пункти — якийсь за -а, якийсь за -у). Як на мене, що більше вузьких випадків буде розписано на цьому сайті, то краще. Але, мабуть, я в меншині…

Comment: От інтуїтивно мені здається, що тут має бути -у — це можна обгрунтувати правилом «більшість складних безсуфіксних слів». Але ж ці слова також можна притулити до «терміни іншомовного походження, які позначають … структурні елементи» або «назви технічних реалій» — і тоді мало б бути -а. Навіть словники сперечаються в подібних випадках (зокрема шановані мною словники Кочерги/Кратка/Мейнаровича часто пропонують поширити -у на ряд математичних термінів, яка в [теж шанованих мною] словниках НАНУ з -а).

Comment: От щойно я знову перечитав правила від початку до кінця. І я не знаю, яка правильна відповідь тут. У мене б рука не піднялася закривати… (Але якщо для когось це очевидно, то, будь ласка, напишіть хоча б у коментах/чаті, який пункт правил це роз'яснює…)

Comment: @Sasha, Re: *"А я. якщо чесно, на боці автора"* — уточніть, ви на боці автора **котрого з двох однакових** запитань? — цього чи того, що вже існує на сайті і отримало вичерпну відповідь? Поясніть, який контент повинен бути у відповіді на **це** запитання, аби контент не був би присутнім у відповіді на попереднє запитання?

Comment: @Sasha, я вам вже казав і кажу ще раз. Проста людина сама по собі може помилятися скільки завгодно. Модератор повинен (1) глибоко розуміти писані і неписані правила, (2) наполегливо втілювати їх на практиці і — найголовніше — (3) своїм прикладом допомагати новачкам. […]

Comment: @Sasha […] Наразі ми бачимо, по-перше, недостатньо досліджене запитання. Це корінь проблеми. Якби було досліджено, то й відповідь би знайшлася. Друга проблема — небажання автора розібратися у власному питанні, бо це б свідчило про його помилку. І тут постає ваша роль — ви починаєте «рятувати» неякісний контент. Причому не за допомогою редагування, бо це потребувало б вашого часу. А за допомогою коментарів виду *«давайте нічого не міняти»*. А модераторський бейдж, яким позначені ваші коментарі, дає людям привід думати, що ваша особиста (помилкова) думка — це правило на сайті SE.

Comment: @Arseny, я написав [відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/7011/8) на сусіднє запитання. Там є пряма відповідь і на ваше запитання також. Проблема зачіпає досить глибокі лінґвістичні явища, що притаманні не лише українській, але і багатьом слов'янським мовам, але сподіваюся, вам буде цікаво.