# Чи правильно вживати дитячий/дорослий квиток?

Tags: словосполучення, прикметники

У своєму [відео-уроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wZDzCtbmDA&index=19&list=PLpjP6nb03Z4k5Wdj8qOj3s_o49a0f9qxX) Олександр Авраменко запевняє, що неправильно говорити *дитячий/дорослий* абонемент, *дитячий* одяг. Оскільки в словнику дорослий - той, що перестав бути дитиною, змужнів. А абонемент/квиток не може змужніти. Натомість у СУМ-20 прочитала, що:

> ДОРО́СЛИЙ, а, е.
>   Який перестав бути дитиною, змужнів. Стрічаючись з жінками, що мали дорослих синів, вона ставала солодкою і хвалилась дочкою (М. Коцюбинський); Він став тепер дорослим, дужим (С. Чорнобривець);
>   // у знач. ім. доро́слий, лого, ч.; доро́сла, лої, ж. Людина, яка перестала бути дитиною, змужніла. Розмова невеличких хлоп'ят зразу всіх дорослих розбудила (Панас Мирний);
>    // Стос. такої людини. – В літах дитинства, – каже згодом до мене Заболотний, – можливо, закодовано щось вельми для душі необхідне, таке, що потім упродовж усього життя позначається на наших цілком “дорослих” вчинках... (О. Гончар);
>   // **Признач. для такої людини**. Він приїхав учора .. Гратиме у **дорослому фільмі** маленьку, так звану епізодичну роль, майже без слів (В. Нестайко); У носіїв києво-черкаської культури дитячий одяг, на відміну від одягу дорослих, так не прикрашався, він мав лише поодинокі підвіски (з наук. літ.);
>   // Який досяг повної зрілості (про тварин, комах і т. ін.). На весь розвиток нематоди – від яйця до дорослого стану – потрібно близько 1,5 місяця (з наук. літ.).
>
> ДИТЯ́ЧИЙ, а, е.
>    1. Прикм. до дити́на і ді́ти1. Мені здалося, що несподівано вернулись мої давні дитячі літа (І. Нечуй-Левицький); Дитячий сміх розноситься в садах (В. Сосюра);
>     // **Признач. для дітей**. Казку сю я хотіла послать в Галичину в **дитячий журнал**, якщо вдасться мені добре ця проба, то писатиму більш (Леся Українка); Якась сільська молодиця пильно приглядалась до двомісної дитячої коляски (Є. Гуцало);

То чи Олександр Авраменко не в той словник дивився, чи я помилилась у розумінні цих термінів? Чи справді неправильно вживати дитячий/дорослий квиток, дитячий/дорослий одяг?

Comment: Я більше вірю СУМ-20 :).

Comment: Можливо, О. Авраменко каже про те, як воно мало б бути за логікою мови (чи колись було), а СУМ-20 фіксує те, як де-факто люди кажуть/пишуть (хай навіть і недолуго). [Ось](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14691&page=478) (друге значення), наприклад, приклад узаконення того, про що мовознавці неодноразово казали, що так казати не можна ([1](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53382/25975.html), [2](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53394/33198.html), [3](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bHrnX3OneA)).

Comment: Моє особисте рішення: ми можемо вирішити для себе не використовувати певні вирази (що вважаємо їх нелогічними, негарними абощо — навіть якщо вони присутні в словниках), але не можемо чекати цього від інших чи докоряти їм за те, що вони їх уживають (бо мова — це те, як люди де-факто кажуть, а не те, що хтось собі надумав).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запитання, як і багато подібних, не про пана Авраменка, а про слово «правильно» у самому запитанні *«Чи **правильно** вживати […]?»*

«Правильність» [може мати декілька значень](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/437/8):

- **«Нормативне слово / усталена норма»** — це коли слово чи словосполучення фіксується у поважних джерелах. СУМ — поважне джерело¹, а отже *дорослий/дитячий квиток* **є усталеною нормою** — особливо, якщо підтверджується також іншими джерелами;
- **Питоме** — це поняття, яке відображає актуальний вжиток, а значить, змінюється з плином часу.

  **Приклад:** Раніше слово *пошта* мало значення «листи паперу, рясно всіяні чорнилом». Тепер це, значною мірою, *електронна пошта*, а не якась інша.

  **Приклад:** СУМ [фіксує](http://sum.in.ua/s/chervonyj) словосполучення *Червоний куток*:

  > Червоний куток — приміщення на підприємстві, в гуртожитку тощо, відведене для культурно-освітньої роботи.

  Вочевидь, це словосполучення є наслідком красно-коричневої окупації. Воно **є нормативним, але вийшло з питомого вжитку**.

  Так само, апеляція до того, що квиток не може подорослішати, має право на існування. Іншими словами, пан Авраменко **апелює до зміни** питомого вжитку цих слів. І якщо він переконає² велику кількість людей, то тоді це словосполучення **перестане бути питомим**.

---

¹) …незважаючи на його (allegedly) численні недоліки, як-то занадто великий вплив канцеляриту <s>який у деяких країнах відіграє роль державної мови :-)</s>

²) або хтось може вважати, що вже переконав