# Відео чи видиво?

Tags: вживання-слів, запозичені-слова

Ві́део (від лат. video — дивлюся, бачу) – запозичена з латинської мови словоформа, яка за інерцією охопила українську і багато інших мов. Не відміняється, і цим створює незручності. Не можна сказати “Багато відеа”, або на тому “відеу”.

Видиво -“те, що видно, що сприймається зором”. Словоформа, яка походить від давнього кореня, і прослідковується у низці споріднених слів: видіти, видно, видноколо, виднота, провидіння тощо.

“Видиво” подібне до латинського “відео”, що підходить для ефекту звикання.

Слово відповідає значення процесу, який триває. Тобто, процесу споглядання чогось. Водночас, цілком може застосовуватися як означення певного масиву інформації, який призначений для проглядання, для видіння.

Згадується у академічному російсько-українському словнику 1924-1933 року (до процесів “наближення” української мови з російською):
Зре́лище – видо́вище, видо́висько, ви́диво, диво́висько, диво́вище, дивови́жа, дивогля́дь (-ди).

Відмінюване, що особливо корисно для зручності вживання. Видиво, багато видива, у цьому видиві, на цих видивах тощо.

Питання: 1) чи підходить це слово як повноцінний замінник усталеного слова "відео"? 2) Чи достатньою є підстава мати внутрішньомовний аналог цього слова для того, аби форсувати цей процес заміни? 3) якому слову ви віддали б перевагу: усталеному запозиченому чи місцевому новотвору?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Цей допис містить пропозицію, але не містить запитання. *«Ваша думка?»* прямо запрошує до відповідей, що ґрунтуються лише на власній думці (opinion-based answers), що прямо суперечить [правилам](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) цього сайту і мережі Stack Exchange. **У чому полягає запитання?**

Comment: У тому, чи бачите ви раціональною таку пропозицію? Чи на вашу думку, це слабкий аргумент?

Comment: @BohdanHdal Питання має мати конкретну відповідь, інакше відповіді будуть opinion-based,  що суперечить правилам на сайтах мережі SE. Ви вже запитували на сайтах SE, тому ви маєте знати ці правила. bytebuster залишив лінк, але ці правила є на кожному сайті мережі і вони універсальні.

Comment: То мені видаляти цю гілку? Бо ж питання вжитку чи не вжитку певних слів - це частково річ, яка є предметом свідомої волі його використання на основі розуміння, що слово достатньо влучне.

Comment: @BohdanHdal, на мою думку, видаляти — не варто; варто — виправити недолік. Недолік полягає в тому, що з цією ввідною інформацією можна сформулювати цілу низку запитань. Тобто, усі оці 7 параграфів тексту, за якими може слідувати різне запитання. Приклади: (1) чи є слово «видиво» [усталеним](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/420/8)? (відп. — ні); (2) чи є воно питомим? (відп. — так); (3) чи є слово «видиво» синонімом слова «відео»? (відп. — так); (4) які дії я, як простий громадянин, можу робити, щоб популяризувати це слово?; (5) і багато інших різних запитань, що мають обʼєктивну відповідь

Comment: @BohdanHdal Re: *«Бо ж питання вжитку чи не вжитку певних слів»* — от саме цього ми і не знаємо: **яке са́ме питання вжитку?**

Comment: Дякую. Я спробую

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Чи підходить це слово як повноцінний замінник усталеного слова "**відео**"?

З етимологічного словника схоже, що слова **відео** та **видиво** є спорідненими, але мають дещо різне значення.

Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 1. 1982.

> Вид. ... **Видиво**, [видище] - сон, привид. ... Лат. **video** "бачу".

В словнику ці слова закріплені з не зовсім різним значенням, але описано по різному.

Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005.

> **Видиво** - 1. Те, що видно, що сприймається зором. 2. Видіння, примара.
>
> **Відео** - Усе, що пов'язане з отриманням зображення предметів на екрані
>   за допомогою електронних засобів (відеокамера, відеомонітор,
>   відеопроєктор та ін.).

Отже на сьогодні слова **відео** та **видиво** мають різне значення та споріднене походження.

#### 2 Чи достатньою є підстава мати внутрішньомовний аналог цього слова для того, аби форсувати цей процес заміни?

Це питання вказує на те, що слова **відео** та **видиво** є тотожними, що по суті, а це доведено в попередньому питанні, є не так. Тобто повністю вже не можна відповісти на це запитання. Я зможу відповісти суб'єктивно на наступне схоже запитання.

Чи достатньою є підстава мати українське подібне слово для того, щоб прискорити заміну іноземного слова на українське?

Підстава мати українське подібне слово до іноземного з подібним значенням, яке можна відмінювати (тобто краще пристосоване до нашої мови) - є достатньою підставою для прискорення цієї заміни. Адже тоді його простіше буде використовувати.

#### 3 Якому слову ви віддали б перевагу: усталеному запозиченому чи місцевому новотвору?

По суті це слово вже не є новотвором і воно вже має значення, яке по суті правильніше описує те, що відбувається "**Те, що видно, що сприймається зором.**". Але з опису стає зрозумілим, що видивом може бути все. Стіл, стілець, комаха, що біжить як на екрані так і поза ним. Чи не занадто воно широке? Хоча і відео по суті має таке саме значення з огляду на використання його в латинській мові.

На основі описаного вище я віддаю свій голос на користь слова **видиво** через його краще пристосування до української мови.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь

Answer (score 0):

**Відео** - це запис події чи явища в цифровому форматі, який можна переглянути повторно необмежену кількість разів.

**Видиво** - це подія або явище, що може спостерігати людина або декілька людей в той момент коли воно відбувається. Також може набувати значення "видіння" або "марево", якщо воно виникає лише в уяві людини, що його спостерігає.

Нехай і дотичні, але це **два різні поняття**. Не можна ліву ногу замінити лівою лапою.

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди додавайте посилання, які підтверджують ваші означення та твердження. Також має сенс уважно читати текст запитання і зосереджувати відповідь на тому, щоб насправді відповідати на запитання, яке вказано у останньому параграфі.

Comment: Будь ласка не видаляйте мої коментарі до моїх відповідей!

Comment: Як взагалі отих от професорів з 60-х, що кожною своєю думкою пригнічували українську мову можна вважати за поважні джерела?