# "Бути корисними"

Tags: вживання-слів

Підкажіть, будь ласка, чи має право на життя такий вираз: "Чекатимемо на нову можливість *бути корисними* Вам"? Якщо ні - як краще висловитися? "можливість стати Вам в пригоді"? Або "можливість принести Вам користь"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту! Це вже друге ваше запитання такої природи, тому хочу спрямувати ваші дослідження у правильному напрямку. Справа в тім, що запитання виду «чи має право на існування…?» або «Як вважаєте, чи можна вважати використання…?» є суто суб'єктивними (opinion-based). Навіть наукові роботи з лінгвістики мають різні думки щодо *«права на існування»* слів та словосполучень, ба більше — пересічні користувачі (деякі з яких, на додачу, діє за покликом своєї інтуїції, а не на основі академічних знань). […]

Comment: Саме тому я мусив проголосувати за закриття як вашого попереднього, так і цього запитань. Правильно поставлене запитання має очікувати науково обґрунтовану відповідь — найчастіше, одну. Наприклад: «чи є слово/словосполучення X [**усталеним та самостійним**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/420/8)?» Інше запитання «чи є слово X **питомим*?» — і відповіді на ці два запитання можуть бути протилежними, але завжди цілком обґрунтованими.

Comment: Тепер далі. Цей допис містить два запитання: «чи має право на життя…?» (opinion-based, замінити на «чи є усталеним/питомим») і «чим замінити…?» Це два запитання, їх варто розносити на два окремих дописи. Окрім того, у запитанні виду «чим замінити» ви надали список кандидатів, які ви розглядали (це добре), але не пояснили, чи вас не влаштували ці кандидати. Така інформація дозволить авторам потенційних відповідей не повторювати роботу, яку ви вже виконали.

Comment: Сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) містять інформацію, корисну для розуміння того, як працює цей сайт, і як оформлювати дописи.

Comment: І ще — вітання і сигнатури не використовуються у дописах на цьому сайті. :)